# Sum of values from my Firebase database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am using a really simple query to ge the sum of the "suly" values from my database but i just get back the whole object:

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private firebasedb: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.firebasedb.list("/fogasok/").subscribe(_data => {



      let sulySum=_data.reduce((sum, item)=>sum+item.suly);
      console.log("nézzük meg a sumot",sulySum);

    });


  }
```

[image]
I would like to go through all the objects in fogasok and sum the "suly". Also if anyone has an idea, how could i do the following i would be super grateful:
SUmming the "suly" for the months (based on the "datum") so i can make a beautiful chart that how much was the "suly" in each month.

Answer (score 0):

solved:

```
  let sulySum=_data.reduce((sum,item)=>sum+item.suly,0);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.